landing on specific <input type="radio">tabs based on the clicked link
I am new to html, css and JS.
I want to click "Find out what Amy likes" on web_page_1, to the "pear" tab on web_page_2.
It seems i need to put a # anchor to the href of "Find out what Amy likes". But I don't know how and what should the anchor be. As in the attached picture, i made the tabs on web_page_2 in input tag radio type.
Welcome to help if you have a solution. Thanks a lot!


   
   <!-- web_page_1 -->
   <a href=“#">
      <h1>Find out what Amy likes</h1>
   </a>
   
   <!-- web_page_2 -->
   
   <section id = page-tabs>
    <div class="page_tabs_container">

        <input type="radio" name="tab" id="1" checked />
        <label for="1">
        <div class="tab-name">Apple</div>
        <div class="tab-content">

        <input type="radio" name="tab" id="2"/>
        <label for=“2”>
        <div class="tab-name">pear</div>
        <div class="tab-content">


        <input type="radio" name="tab" id="3"/>
        <label for=“3”>
        <div class="tab-name">banana</div>
        <div class="tab-content">





There is no way to select a radio button by URL alone; this needs additional JavaScript.

Besides, I know such "pure CSS solutions" might seems tempting - but they usually fare quite badly in terms of accessibility. A proper, JS-based tab system, like f.e. the one Bootstrap provides, is usually much, much preferable.

@C3roe thank you for reply. I'll look into JS solutions

@Rob !!oh yeaaaa, it doesnt indeed. lol thanks
